# Every Lie algebra contains a maximal proper Lie subalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I am working though the proof of Proposition 6.2 in Erdmann's ["Introduction to Lie Algebras"](https://books.google.de/books?id=Kbh3-hvDSbIC&lpg=PR5&ots=WHiiJ_8Q4L&dq=existence%20of%20maximal%20lie%20subalgebra%20erdmann&lr&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I can't verify that every Lie subalgebra of $L \subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ contains a maximal (proper) Lie subalgebra.

How would I prove this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimension of $V$ is finite, consider $S(L)$ the of Lie subalgebras distinct of $L$, it is not empty since it contains $0$, an element of maximum dimension is a maximum proper Lie subalgebra.